# Image of a closed set is Borel

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I got stuck with the following statement. Let $U \subset \mathbb{R^k}$ be an open subset and let $g : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function but I think continuity should suffice. Let $C \subset U$ be a closed subset then the claim is that $g(C)$ is a borel set. I apologize if this problem has been asked before. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: What is $U$? If $U$ is, say, a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ then $g(U)$ is a countable union of compact sets...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : this doesn't work with subsets which can't be get with a compact exhaustion no ? But if $U$ is open then it works indeed.

Comment: @Baloown I was only concerned with $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R^k}$. Thanks for the comments. I am not sure if the statement is valid in greater generality. So I will edit the question suitably.

Comment: @Baloown Right you are. I meant to say "open subset of $\Bbb R^n$", sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get $U=\bigcup_{k=1}^{+\infty}U_k$ a compact exhaustion of the open $U.$ Then consider $C_k=C\cap U_k$ which is a compact set because closed set in the compact set $U_k$, and then get that $g(C)=\bigcup_{k=1}^{+\infty}g(C_k).$ As $g(C_k)$ are continuous images of compact sets so are compact and so are closed sets, you get that $g(C)$ is a borel set as countable union of closed sets which are borel sets.